# Meaning of "in compliance with"

Tags: meaning

I want to get this phrase cleared:

> in compliance with

Is this equal to "adhering to"?

> People should live in compliance with government rules.

Is this sentence is correct? My idea of the sentence is that people should live according to rules.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. First of all, you have to show us what kind of research you did before you posted this question, i.e. [compliance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compliance) and [adhere](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adhere). The verb form of compliance is **comply** and you need to look it up, too. Unless you show us your research, your question could be closed as **off-topic**. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your thinking.

**Comply**- to act or be in accordance with wishes, requests, demands, requirements, conditions, etc. (sometimes followed by with);

**Adhere**-to hold closely or firmly (usually followed by to);

(dictionary.com)

Examples:

If you don't **comply with** the rules, you will be punished severely.

If you don't **adhere to** the rules, you will be punished severely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you tell me whether this is correct. "If you don't live in accordance with rules, you will be punished severely. "

Comment: Yes, that is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

> People should live in compliance with government rules.

I find this a bit hard to interpret. It seems to suggest that the government has rules for how to live, or whether to live, or under what circumstances to live, and that people should comply with these rules; but it sounds a bit draconian.

If you simply mean that people should follow government rules (not necessarily just the rules relating to living), then you can write:

> People should obey the law.